# PowerShell Resolve-DnsName Returns Random IP For Hosts without Records

Tags: powershell

I've been working a script with both PS 5 & 7.

I'm writing a script to determine whether or not there is a DNS entry for a host.

When I query for a hostname I KNOW is NOT in our DNS zone, the command consistently returns the IP of a member server. It's the same one consistently. It's not a DNS Server or related to the script in any way, no matter what nonsense names I supply.

I have tried various approaches to this, including (Resolve-DnsName -Name poopyface).ipAddress.

Or another example:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $IPAddresses = Resolve-DnsName poopyface | Select-Object -Property IPAddress
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> write-host $IPAddresses
@{IPAddress=10.221.33.79}
```

Host "poopyface" is not a valid DNS entry in our zone, but 10.221.33.79 is the address of a random server.

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this?

As described above, I have tried several different approaches. But I can't remember other ones. I've been banging on this all day.

Comment: When I try to resolve a known-nonexisting host in our network, `Resolve-DNSName` throws an error.

Comment: Is the problem definitely with ```Resolve-DnsName``` or could it be with your dns in general? For example, if you try ```nslookup poopyface``` in a regular command prompt do you see the same address? You can also try ```nslookup -debug poopyface``` to see exactly what is being returned by your dns server - that might help narrow down the problem...

Comment: Hi, Jeff. 
PS C:\Users\~salcicct> resolve-DnsName -Name unknownhost
Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
unknownhost                                    A      30    Answer     10.221.33.79
Still get the same IP of an existing host.

Comment: @mclayton nslookup returns the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

When I try I get *"Resolve-DnsName : poopyface : DNS server failure"*..:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> $IPAddresses = Resolve-DnsName poopyface | Select-Object -Property IPAddress
```

*Resolve-DnsName : poopyface : DNS server failure*

Are you able to ping it? -:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> ping poopyface
```

*Ping request could not find host poopyface. Please check the name and try again.*

Does it (the script) work ok with other domain names like google.com?
Sounds like you got to clear it out of your DNS if that "host" is not supposed to be there.

Does this issue on occur on a particular host?
Maybe something in your hosts file..

Try doing a:  "`tracert poopyface`" in the `cmd` and see which network it lands on.

Something else that has come to mind. This is PS and I have personally had issues with variables in the past and might be worth looking at ensure the variable is new\fresh everytime it is created.

Can you share the script? Possibly that variable has already been filled in.

Comment: ping of poopeyface succeeds with the  IP of the other member server responding, even after /flushdns. Tracert shows 1 hope to the IP address of the other server. I have been testing in a PS 7 shell - I get exactly the same result with resolve-dnsname and nslookup. Using the same command to retrieve "www.google.com" works just fine, as is with the hosts that actually DO reside in our DNS Zone. I will try running these commands on a different host tomorrow. And I will post the full script tomorrow. I have to get to something else tonight. Thanks.

Comment: Ok Thanks for checking... something else worth trying is using the nbtstat command and also confirm there is nothing lurking in the Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file (s)..

Comment: Thank you for your notes. I'll run nbtstat. I have already verified that the hosts file is default - everything is commented out.

Comment: Something else that would might help here now is looking into the eventlogs on DHCP\DNS servers to try track it down.. This might help for help for example-: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj878332(v=ws.11)#tracking-by-host-name